# How to solve TablviewCell Content Overlapping Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In tableview I have customcell reusable cell which overlap content of privious cell or last cell content overlap with first cell when scroll Tableview

Comment: Can you please share your code? A piece of code will be much helpful

Comment: Shouw your code and some screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should set properties that depend on `indexPath` in `viewForCell` function, always.